# Incorporating Two Angular Projects in One Ionic 4 App

Tags: java, android, angular, ionic-framework

I have a requirement to run 2 different angular projects in 1 Ionic App. The main reason for this is because they will serve as 2 different parts of the App and the second part of the app will be triggered by an android service, so I won't know from Angular side that it was triggered by the service.

By default, the normal **"index.html"** will be launched if the app starts, but I have incorporated an android service into the project which will in turn will Launch a JAVA class which will load another html file.

By Default:

```
public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // enable Cordova apps to be started in the background
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null && extras.getBoolean("cdvStartInBackground", false)) 
        {
            moveTaskToBack(true);
        }

        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        loadUrl(launchUrl);
    }
}
```

When **Service** is triggered:

```
public class ServiceTrigger extends CordovaActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // enable Cordova apps to be started in the background
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null && extras.getBoolean("cdvStartInBackground", false)) {
            moveTaskToBack(true);
        }

        loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/second_part.html");
    }
}
```

I have created an additional Ionic App which I use to build the "Second_Part" of the app. I use the **www** content of this part of the app, and copy it over to the www directory of the Main App. I found that the "second_part.html" loads fine, but the issue comes while bootstrapping the "Second_Part" App. Once "second_part.html" loaded, the screen is just white, but when I just add plain HTML to "second_part.html", then it displays the HTML. I have also debugged via Android Studio but couldn't see errors.

Not sure if this is even possible, nor if anyone has ever attempted this. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong or if there is an alternative to pass parameters to the Main Part of the app to tell it that it was triggered by the Android Service?

Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I need to specify the full path for all css and js files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./android_asset/www/app2/runtime.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script>
```

After I changed the paths, everything worked perfect!

With this said, I moved the entire second part of the app to it's own folder inside the www directory, thus I also had to change the url Cordova has to load:

```
loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/app2/index.html");
```

This is just a cleaned approach and will work well with Code Push.